# Digital Transactions Question | Does Google assure it's working in order to approve?

Tags: actions-on-google

I can confirm 3 instances on a newly released action where people selected the premium upgrade feature.  All of these did not result in a transaction, according to my console.logs I can't really determine what is happening.  But my question is, would Google have approved this action if this step had an error?

I tested it (after enabling live transactions) and it did work, of course when I access the action it says "staring the test version" but the test/draft version is identical to the currently published version.

I'm currently outside the US so I tried to buy on a different login/different account and when I do that, it asks me to set up payments, then when Play opens the whole thing crashes (on Play's side, not in Google Assistant) so I assume it's because I used a VPN just to get that request and then Play determined I was not "billing eligible" being outside the US.

Anyway my main question is it possible there is something wrong with the code if 1) my live transaction does work and 2) Google approved the app in the first place?